# How can I get all five cubs up the river without dying?

Tags: shelter

In the third chapter, I can't seem to get my cubs up the river without one of them dying. It's always exactly one that dies, and the waves stop afterward. I'm trying to make it through the game without any cubs dying, so this is getting very frustrating.

How can I get all five cubs up the river without dying? Where can they stand and not get hit by the waves?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Steam Community Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=247192787), you can do it using the following method:

> There are some stepping stones by the river. Go across that and you will see two fox/weasel type things. You can hunt them for food. When crossing the river be careful as the current could swoop across and wash away a baby as you cross. I would recommend that you wait first for the two big wooshy wave things to go past before crossing. As those hedgehogs said “stop, think, and go!”
>
> Once you cross the stream you will see a very long stream with lots of stepping stones. You have to wait for the current to whoosh past then you have to RUN FOR YOUR LIIIFEE up the stream to get to the safe bit up ahead. Make sure that you stop every now and then and hide behind the rocks so that none of your babies get swept away. Once you get past the stream the exit should be close. Just follow the path until you see it.